# import XML in google spreadsheet

Tags: xml, google-api, google-sheets

I have one question/problem
I have some xml. Example:

> api.mysite.net/xml/user/id/1145

now, i would like to get this 1145 from my sheet. It should look like:

> =ImportXML("http://api.mysite.net/xml/user/id/C5"; "/*")

In c5, there would be id :)
Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use the & to concatenate the strings, e.g.

```
=ImportXML("http://api.mysite.net/xml/user/id/"&C5; "/*")
```